# Creating a website with multiple apps, plain PHP apps and static pages with Symfony?

Tags: symfony

My boss is a big fan of buzzwords and he insists that we should create our new website using Symfony 2.

I have already used Symfony to develop several apps, but the problem I encounter now is that this website consists of several apps, static webpages and even good old PHP apps consisting mainly of spaghetti code.

- Would I need various installations of Symfony, one per app or can I
  use the same? Would I use bundles for this, or is there a better way?
- Does it make any sense to serve the static webpages using Symfony?
- If I install Symfony on the root of the site so that I can use it to create a common login system, can I instruct Symfony to ignore the requests to the old apps?

Comment: Here's a nice presentation about the topic: http://www.slideshare.net/fabrice.bernhard/modernisation-of-legacy-php-applications-using-symfony2-php-northeast-conference-2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Just like you suggest: for the apps I would use one Symfony installation and then a Bundle for each app
- For the sake of coherent integration I would serve the static pages from Symfony, perfomancewise this doesn't make any difference, since they'll be served nicely from Symfony cache. As of Symfony 2.2 integration of static pages is also pretty straightforward done by the FrameworkBundle:Template:template in the routing configuration of your bundle. (e.g. see here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-cache-support-for-static-pages)
- As for the requests for old apps, I should think that these would best be caught and redirected to the new corresponding apps whilst rewriting the params according to the needs of your new apps. This would probably be done by htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, build some kind of test harness around all the pages that work today and should work afterwards.
2. If the whole website is being served off the same domain or you're sharing entities or some other configuration, then definitely use one installation of Symfony. You don't want to be updating multiple installations, or manually pushing data from one database to another. If they're on different domains, and you want each user to have only one login, use SSO.
3. Look at your traffic for whether to serve static pages through Symfony or not. If you get 1000s of concurrent users, and 80% of the traffic is to those static pages, then I'd say be pragmatic and server them from a CDN. On the other hand, if your traffic is a bit lower or more spread through the dynamic content then it would be easier if everything was in Symfony.
4. You can either block or forward the URLs, though it would be better to do it through the webserver if possible (Apache, Nginx), as loading the whole Symfony framework just to do a redirect is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bouscher. You can each distribute your apps into bundles. Using Symfony for static pages doesn't hurt at all especially that you will stick on using the framework for the apps, its better to keep it intact all in one platform. For the static pages you can create like a bundle that contains nothing but "views"(your static pages) using twig. Just create some routing rules then you'll be fine. Thats what I did with mine.

Will you rewrite your old php apps? or just tweak it a bit to be somehow symfony friendly?